# MongoDB - How to consume printjson output in Java

Tags: java, json, mongodb, jackson

I need to communicate with MongoDB shell via Java
To explain in short, I am using something like Runtime.exec (commons exec specifically) to call [MongoDB shell in --eval mode](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Scripting+the+shell)

Using this approach, I am able to successfully invoke MongoDB commands, retrieve the output into a stream (and print to stdout for example)

All is well till this point.

**I need to now "parse" this output into something like an array of [JSONObject](http://json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html)** 

(I can make use of any JSON library like Jackson, etc. that may be appropriate for this)
so that I can "massage" the output based on some requirements. (Change the format, remove some key value pairs, etc.)

When I look at the output generated by printjson in case of arrays at least, it does not seem to be a valid json array but rather valid json objects separated by new line without the comma in between or enclosing [] that would make it a valid array.

In this case, any suggestions on how to parse this output into some kind of holder objects that I can use to read/modify key value pairs?

I don't have the json commands at compile time but do know that these commands will always end in a printjson

**EDIT -**

So to simplify, for example, I am looking for a way to parse the following output into Java Objects -
(The individual key/value pairs are not known at compile time)

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4db0e0289523f82ff6cd90d4"),
    "calendar_date" : "2009-11-10",
    "product_id" : 8,
    "channel" : "website",
    "country" : "USA",
    "total_unit_count" : 740,
    "total_amount" : 11367.29
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4db0e0289523f82ff6cd90d5"),
    "calendar_date" : "2009-11-10",
    "product_id" : 8,
    "channel" : "website",
    "country" : "Australia",
    "total_unit_count" : 740,
    "total_amount" : 13893.09
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4db0e0289523f82ff6cd90d6"),
    "calendar_date" : "2009-11-10",
    "product_id" : 8,
    "channel" : "retail",
    "country" : "USA",
    "total_unit_count" : 13,
    "total_amount" : 8296.89
}
```

Comment: You would use a Java JSON parser, of which there are many listed on one of the sites you link; http://json.org/

Comment: Is there a reason you do not want to use MongoDB Java driver? The holder object in that case would be DBObject and your code will be far more cleaner than parsing eval'd JSON output.

Comment: @lobster - This java program needs to accept javascript commands so I am not sure how/if I could use the Java driver.

Comment: There is an API in the driver that lets you send commands to the server (more or less like you do on the console). The javadoc site for MongoDB is broken so I cant look it up, but lemme reply as soon as I can find it.

Comment: Too bad the javadoc site is still down (due to AWS outage earlier today) :(

Comment: @lobster - Its up now but browsing through the docs, I still don't see a way to pass the same set of commands that I would on a shell.

Comment: Sorry I woke up late due to the day off :) Here is the function that I was talking about http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.5.3/com/mongodb/DB.html#eval

Comment: +1. I tried it. If I pass a simple 3+3, I do get back 6. If I pass a js command like db.foo.find().forEach(printjson), I get back null (The same command returns 20 documents via shell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was looking for does not seem possible at the moment.

What I ended up doing was to shell out the mongo calls, obtain the result stream in java, JSONize the result (get rid of object_id since i dont need it, convert dates appropriately, etc.) and then generate a json object from this modified result string.
Ugly hack but the only one that seemed possible and it works.

If you ever find yourself in a similar boat and have specific questions, post in the comment below and I will help if I can.

Answer (score 1):

You can run anything you can write in javascript in java directly (using the mongodb java driver).

It is a bad idea to shell out and try to consume the output from java. Instead you should run the commands/queries directly from the java using the driver.

Comment: I have a legacy system that "produces" queries for the mongo shell. Are you saying I can take these plain text queries that the shell understands and pass them to the mongo java driver as is? what method? Last time I checked, there was nothing in the mongo java driver that would allow this.

Comment: You can use JSON.parse(...) to convert from a json string to a DBObject which you can use as query restriction. That allows you to take a string like this: `{field:"value"}` and run a query with it.

Comment: Thanks for giving further thought to the question but the queries are not json, they are javascript, originally meant to be run against the mongo shell.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that com.mongodb.util.JSON does not extend DBObject, I'm not sure why people claim you can do collection.insert(JSON.parse(some json)). is there another way to insert the json that i'm missing?

edit: the answer is easy here, but isn't in the documentation. simply add a cast:

```
collection.insert((DBObject)JSON.parse(some json ... ));
```